# Binding image based on database id

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, binding

I'm using SQLite and I have table which contains table with fields: `id` and `name`

In my project I have folder graphics/pictures and there my pictures are named like: 1.png, 2.png etc.

I save all records into ObservableCollection and then I set this as a source to my ListBox.

Is there any chance to bind that photos to each item on the list based on id from table and the name of picture in folder?

I have tried smth like `Source="graphic/pictures/{Binding id}.png` but that seems to be bad way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it works (and not able to try right now) but you could use StringFormat (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) or a converter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) that returns the full path

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a class with image as string

```
      public class Img
       {
        public string thumb { get; set; }
       }
```

In Code:

```
   for (i = 0; i < observablecollection.Length; i++)
    {
    Img sqlimage = new Img()
    {
    thumb = "/PhoneApp1;component/images/" + observablecollection[i].Id + ".jpg"
    };

    listbox1.Items.Add(sqlimage);
    }


  <ListBox  Name="listBox1" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Img}" DataContext="{Binding}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto">
   <Image Height="165" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Source="{Binding thumb}"/>
</StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       </ListBox>
```